# masking in react js material ui textfield for url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, masking

I want to mask url regex like user has to type http or https and then :// auto applies then after entire url.
I am using material ui textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 3rd party library for the masking, strait from the docs:

> Integration with 3rd party input libraries You can use third-party
> libraries to format an input. You have to provide a custom
> implementation of the  element with the inputComponent
> property.
>
> The following demo uses the react-imask and react-number-format
> libraries.

In the docs link below are implemented some examples.
Ref: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries